# Best URL for cars related website?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting

If this was your website, what will be the URLs for each car on sale?

```
http://www.autoscout24.eu/Details.aspx?id=247572735&asrc=ha
```

I'm working on a car dealership website. What should be the best URL?
Consider also that the company can have more models of the same car.

I'm not asking for a url scheme, there are a lot of similar questions. My question is: in a car dealership website what is the best url for a car? What are by you the best variables I've to put on the url.

Brand, model, year, location, color, miles/km, etc.

This website, that url, this particulary case: what will you choose for urls? (even not in the following list)

```
audi_q5_2009.html
audi_q5_2009_used.html
audi_q5_2009_used.html
audi_q5_2009_used_in_alcobendas.html
audi_q5_2009_used/247572735.html
```

Comment: The first (and short) one, easier to remember for users.

Comment: That is really not a problem because every car has a short url.

Comment: My question was more specific. A car related website (so with a lot of variables such brand, model, years, traction, color, etc etc). It wasn't just a request of a url scheme.

Comment: Edit your question to make it more specific as per your comment then and we'll vote to reopen it.

Comment: Question Edited